# OSB - JCA Adapter connection error

Tags: eclipse, soa, jdeveloper, jca, osb

when I try a flow in OEPE I get this error in my domain's log:

"nested exception is: BINDING.JCA-11812

Interaction Processing Error.
Error when processing the execution of the interaction to API,[SCHEMA].[PACKAGE].[STORED_PROCEDURE]. An error has ocurred when processing the interaction to call to API,[SCHEMA].[PACKAGE].[STORED_PROCEDURE]. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Make sure that the XML that contains parameter data fits with the XSD parameter definitions. This exception is unrecoverable, probably because of a modelling error."

(NOTE: My OSB is in Spanish. I translated this)

I'm making a flow that receives a SOAP message (HTTP), and sends parameter data to a Stored Procedure in a database. I created a JCA Adapter with JDeveloper to reference the database in my office, and the stored procedure I created on it. I put the jca, wsdl, and xsd in OEPE and generated a business service.

So, I have 2 flows, one that receives the SOAP and from the data on its attributes sets a concatenated string of those attributes which I replace on the body of the message (using soap envelope), and route it to the second flow.

In the second flow, I just route directly to the business services that uses the JCA. Already tested it, but it doesn't connect to the database according to above's error.

Can someone help me on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Check your JCA uri. You must have DBAdaptor (in weblogic console) pointing to same JCA uri that is in your JCA generated file.
Also the DataSource you have should have JNDI same as that is in DBAdaptor connection xADataSourceName.

This is connection issue. Try verifying the datasource and DBAdaptor settings as I said above. Hope it will resolve your issue.